# Survey Summary Web Part not showing correct number of responses

Tags: 2010, survey-list

I created an out of the box survey where till date 116 employees responded but the Survey Summary Web Part on overview.aspx page shows Number of Responses as 30 (as given in the image). Why there is a difference? Why not the Summary Web Part shows Number of Responses as 116?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most likely some of your users didn't complete the survey. These items are not reachable using API, but can be seen in the content database as checked out items with no published version.